# Linq: How to make an object from linq result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 tables Continent, Country and City. I need to make an object of Continent type that has its countries and countries have their cities.

Continent -->Country--> City like this. Europe --> Germany --> Frankfurt, Berlin,etc..

My code:

```
public partial class Continent
{
    public Continent()
    {
        this.Countries = new HashSet<Country>();
    }

    public int ContinentId { get; set; }
    public string ContinentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}

public partial class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        this.Cities = new HashSet<City>();
    }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ContinentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public virtual Continent Continent { get; set; }
}

public partial class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

var Result = (from a in db.Continents
              join b in db.Countries
                on a.ContinentId equals b.ContinentId
              join c in db.Cities on b.CountryId equals c.CountryId
              where a.ContinentId == 1
              select new
                     {
                         ContinentName = a.ContinentName,
                         CountryName = b.CountryName,
                         CityName = c.CityName
                    });
```

This is the result:

[image]

I need to make an object of type Continent which includes its own counties and cities

Comment: *I need to make an object*  And what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

Use the namespace `System.Entity.Data;`

```
var continent = db.Continents
                  .Include(c => c.Countries.Select(cn => cn.Cities))
                  .FirstOrDefault(c => c.ContinentId == 1);
```

Comment: Thank you :) ...I did exactly what you said but when i looked at the generated t-sql i found a lot of Joins and useless statments

Comment: This query will join continent with country and city tables.

Comment: I wouldn't call a JOIN statement useless in a relational database query...

Comment: Include is only necessary if you need to retain the references to the other types even after closing the database connection, and if you aren't storing the results in some other place.

Comment: @Sahuagin - OP has explicitly said to fetch the relational data as well. Thats why I eager loaded the related entities; as OP neds country and city details, if we do lazy loading thats gonna end up in multiple db hits.

Comment: @Developer not sure what OP is looking for; you might be right, but I can't tell. need more info.

Answer (score 0):

To get the results you indicated you would do something like:

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) {
   var data =
      context
      .Continents
      .SelectMany(continent =>
         continent
         .Countries
         .SelectMany(country =>
            country
            .Cities
            .Select(city =>
               new {
                  ContinentName = continent.Name,
                  CountryName = country.Name,
                  CityName = city.Name
               }
            )
         )
      ).ToList();

   // do something with data
}
```

Comment: In the `.Select(city =>` part, `continent` and `country` are not in scope. This is much easier with query syntax.

Comment: @GertArnold No, they are definitely in scope, because of closure. Yes this might look a lot nicer with query syntax.

Comment: @Sahuagin, Thank you for your help :) ... I am not asking for query i am asking how to map the result to make object an object of type Continent that has its counties and cities, thank you

Comment: @Lucy Not sure what you mean. `Continent` already is "an object of type `Continent` that has its countries and cities". Are you getting an error or something? Use `Continent.Countries` to get countries, and `Country.Cities` to get cities. It already is this way.

Comment: @Lucy maybe you are confused about how actually to pull data from the database? You should have a model class somewhere that you pull data from, as in my code above (`MyContext` in the example, not sure what yours is called).

Comment: @Sahuagin, My friend . I need map that result to have that
 Europe --> Germany --> Frankfurt, Berlin,